# Convert Excel To Text Using Office and Command line

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, command-line, microsoft-office

Is there any command line option to pass to Office's Excel so it can convert .xlsx files into .txt files without showing Excel's GUI?

Comment: What have you researched or tried?

Comment: I just googled "converting excel to text using command line" but I did not find any way doing it by Microsoft's Excel, Just found some third-party applications which can not support Unicode Excel files...

Comment: [See if this helps](http://superuser.com/a/624244/50173). It converts Excel files into txt files (one CSV per sheet). This is done with PowerShell, the successor of the old Windows commandline. Since the conversion is done via a hidden Excel, you won't have problems with Unicode